# Purpose of View and ActionResult in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

What is the purpose of ActionResult and View in mvc of visual studio 2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActionResult is something MVC understands which says that its something which is going to be sent back to the client. (its a little more complicated than this but thats the basic idea). View() is a method that produces a specific kind of action result which is intended to be rendered into an HTML template before getting sent to the client. Theres also other kinds of actionresults such as JSON() which produces a special JSON formated actionresult